# Proof of Gibbs's phenomenon (general case)

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

I am looking for a reference that proves the Gibbs phenomenon in generality. In other words, for a function $f$ which has discontinuity in $x_0$, that the max error around the discontinuity when approximating this function by a fourier series is a given value (see [wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon#Formal_mathematical_description_of_the_phenomenon)). In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon#The_square_wave_example), and many other places, there is a proof for a particular example (as square wave, toothsaw, ...) is there some nice proof for the general case somewhere?